# Python Create Custom Armature without ops

Tags: python, armature

how do you create an armature in Blender Python 2.7x without using bpy.ops? With meshes I would use something like

```
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

I can do something similar with armatures however how do I make the actual bone body? In the outliner I can see the armature object but there is only an origin point in the scene. When using dir on the armature I don’t see an option along the lines of from_pydata.

```
pivot_bone = bpy.data.armatures.new('spam')
object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, pivot_bone)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
print(dir(pivot_bone))
```

Ultimately I would like to use Python to create a custom bone shape.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fairly sure that mesh data is the only one that offers `from_pyData` for others we need to manually position items as we create them, which we can do by reading the py data.

Armatures can get confusing, there are [bones](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Bone.html) as well as [edit bones](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.EditBone.html) that contain the basic armature structure and properties and then there are [pose bones](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html) that stores constraints and animation data for all the action.

Different data paths are used to access different bone data -

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
obj.data.edit_bones # adding, deleting, positioning bones
obj.data.bones # adjusting bone properties
obj.pose.bones # adding constraints, custom shapes...
```

An example of adding some bones and creating a custom mesh then setting it as the custom shape for one of the bones -

```
import bpy, bmesh

arm_obj = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
# must be in edit mode to add bones
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arm_obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
edit_bones = arm_obj.data.edit_bones

b = edit_bones.new('bone1')
# a new bone will have zero length and not be kept
# move the head/tail to keep the bone
b.head = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
b.tail = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

b = edit_bones.new('bone2')
b.head = (1.0, 2.0, 0.0)
b.tail = (1.0, 2.0, 1.0)

# exit edit mode to save bones so they can be used in pose mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# make the custom bone shape
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, cap_ends=False, diameter=0.2, segments=8)
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
b2_shape = bpy.data.objects.new("bone2_shape", me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(b2_shape)
b2_shape.layers = [False]*19+[True]

# use pose.bones for custom shape
arm_obj.pose.bones['bone2'].custom_shape = b2_shape
# use data.bones for show_wire
arm_obj.data.bones['bone2'].show_wire = True
```

Comment: If you try to add a custom shape to the same bone Blender returns error 'key "" not found', is there a way around this? I’m only making one bone, not multiple. 'bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones['Armature'].custom_shape = b2_shape'

Comment: Actually I think I'm just confusing myself now. I put up a script based off what you have shown on pastbin http://pastebin.com/Vs5cAq9S. It makes an armature, adds a bone, creates a mesh, then tries to apply the mesh as a custom bone shape which doesn’t work.

Comment: You need to exit armature edit mode before the non-edit bones can be seen to add the custom shape. You will also find that `armature_object == armature_data`